# Google Maps V3 Javascript: Event listener not being loaded

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, event-handling, dom-events

I don't seem to be able to make Google Maps click event listeners for markers to work. The only detail is that this is being run in a cycle, meaning that in the first time i include the map and run the add markers and their event listeners, the following times I have a function that only adds the markers and the listeners.

This is my `initialize` function and `datasetRealtime` is the array of markers:

```
 function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        scaleControl: true,
        scaleControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
        },
        /* Map Zoom */
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.186968, -8.697792),
        /*Center Coordinate*/
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    realtime_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvasBig"), mapOptions);


    for (var i = 0; i < datasetRealtime.length; i++) {


        var latitude = parseFloat(datasetRealtime[i]["latitude"]);
        var longitude = parseFloat(datasetRealtime[i]["longitude"]);

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: realtime_map,
            title: 'Just some title'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            console.log("it worked")
        });
    }
   }
```

And I am loading it with:

```
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykeygoeshere&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

This is the function that adds the markers and listeners if the map is already loaded:

```
   function addMarkers(){
     for (var i = 0; i < datasetRealtime.length; i++) {


        var latitude = parseFloat(datasetRealtime[i]["latitude"]);
        var longitude = parseFloat(datasetRealtime[i]["longitude"]);

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: realtime_map,
            title: 'Just some title'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            console.log("it worked")
        });
    }
  }
```

**Update**

I am cleaning the markers before I add the new ones with:

```
   function clearOverlays(datasetRealtime) {
       for (var i = 0; i < datasetRealtime.length; i++) {
          datasetRealtime[i].setMap(null);
       }
      datasetRealtime = [];
    }
```

I've tried so many ways, even with closures and I don't seem to be able to make it work. The markers are added, but there's no handler when I click on them (the little hand stays wide open)

Comment: do you mean you want to display address..

Comment: Maneti i'm not sure i understood your comment

Comment: Did you get over this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi the below code will do for marker click also added a [small code](http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/mQEwh/).. sry could'nt look into ur code fully still provided info that would help in solving..

```
var marker = new GMarker(location);
GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
   alert('it works');
});
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Comment: Hi codebreaker, that code is for Google maps v2 and i'm using V3. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The proble might be you are rewriting marker at each for loop.
You have to store your markes in a markersArray object.

Your code will look something like this:

```
var markers = [];
function addMarkers(){
     for (var i = 0; i < datasetRealtime.length; i++) {


        var latitude = parseFloat(datasetRealtime[i]["latitude"]);
        var longitude = parseFloat(datasetRealtime[i]["longitude"]);

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: realtime_map,
            title: 'Just some title'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            console.log("it worked")
        });

        markers.push(marker);
    }
  }
```

That might work!

May I suggest to you a code refactoring: since you have already an addMarkers method it could be simplier to call it in your initialize method than to rewrite the same code there.